# Content type hub ghosts?

Tags: content-type, managed-metadata, metadata, service-application, content-type-hub

In SP 2013 on-premise, I have created a site collection for Content Type Hub, and one for Intranet. The content types are synchronized to the Intranet Site Collection from the CT Hub.

I did some changes to Content Types in the CT hub, i.e change parents and ID's. Of course that would put me in serious trouble, and it did. So I deleted both the site collections, and re-provisioned Content Type hub and content types with new ID's etc, and I also re-provisioned the Intranet Site Collection. While the CT Hub site collection seems to be update, the Intranet Site Collection gets Content Types that are deleted, and old content type stuff.

I have deleted site collections, and re-provisioned. I also run all the timer jobs several times, i.e the Content Type Subscriber and Content Type Subscription jobs.

Is there any thing else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

The data from your old hub lives on in the Managed Metadata Service Application database. The nuclear option would be to delete and recreate your MMD service application to totally purge the data. If this is a production system and you have term sets already in use, you are going to have to recreate that as well, including the GUIDs on all objects.

Comment: Is there any precision strike option here instead of nuclear ? i.e. delete a single column from MMD ?